# Predicting future position given linear velocity and angular velocity at $t=0$

Tags: rotational-kinematics

I'm working on predicting the path of a point in 3D space for a game; at any moment, I'll have the point's linear velocity vector $\vec v (x, y, z)$ in m/s, and angular velocity $\vec\omega$ in rads/s (relative to $x, y, z$ axes) at position $p_0$.

The velocities' magnitudes and relative orientations don't change (that is, the point maintains uniform circular motion), how do I go about predicting the point's position at time $t$?

My assumption at this point is that there is a calculable $\vec r$ that describes uniform circular motion around a central point $o$ such that $\vec v = \vec\omega × \vec r$, and that $\vec r = \frac{\vec v × \vec\omega}{|\vec\omega|^2}$, with $p_0 = o + \vec r$

Given that $\vec v$ will have a constant relative orientation (tangential to the path of uniform circular motion)... from the origin position $o$, the position of the point $p$ at any time $t$ would be calculable as a function of $\vec\omega(t)$, but I'm a bit fuzzy on how to do that in 3D space. I get that I'm close, it's a function of $rt\omega_{x,y,z}$, but I can't get it over the finish line.

Are my assumptions correct, and if so, what is the function that describes the point $p$ at time $t$?

Comment: $\vec v$ and $\vec\omega$ are not independent quantities, so it does not make sense to use both of them. Also, if you're assuming uniform circular motion, why can't you just say $\vec r(t)=(r_0\cos t,r_0\sin t)$?

Comment: So $\omega$ does not represent the rotation of the object, but the rate at which the observation angle changes.

Comment: Given that a point does not or cannot rotate (it has zero spatial dimensions) can you explain what does $\vec{\omega}$ is measuring?

Comment: @Sendjo: I don't understand, unfortunately, as $\vec r$ is in three dimensions, and the resulting vector you've provided is in two dimensions in a flat plane; the plane of motion for this point would be some kind of oblique plane. Also don't I need $\vec v$ to determine the origin point $o$ of the uniform motion?  
  
My understanding is that $\omega$ is measuring the characteristics of the object's adjustments to its path. It's not so much a rotation of a 0-D point but rather the characteristics of its turning radius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If as you mentioned in the comments $\vec{\omega}$ is defined such that

$$ \vec{v} = \vec{\omega} \times ( \vec{p}_0 - \vec{p}_C ) $$

where $\vec{p}_0$ is the position of the object at the time $\vec{v}$ and $\omega$ is measured, and $\vec{p}_C$ is a point on the instant axis of rotation.

To find $\vec{p}_C$ use the vector triple product to get

$$ \require{cancel} \begin{aligned}\vec{\omega}\times\vec{v} & =\vec{\omega}\times\left(\vec{\omega}\times(\vec{p}_{0}-\vec{p}_{C})\right)\\
 & =\vec{\omega}\left(\cancel{\vec{\omega}\cdot(\vec{p}_{0}-\vec{p}_{C})}\right)-(\vec{p}_{0}-\vec{p}_{C})\left(\vec{\omega}\cdot\vec{\omega}\right)\\
\vec{p}_{C} & =\vec{p}_{0}+\frac{\vec{\omega}\times\vec{v}}{\vec{\omega}\cdot\vec{\omega}}
\end{aligned} $$

<sub>The reason for canceling the terms above is because $\vec{p}_C$ can be any point along with the axis of rotation and any terms perpendicular to $\vec{\omega}$ get canceled out by the dot product. So only the parallel terms matter, and we might as well choose them such as to cancel this term.</sub>

Once you have the center of rotation $\vec{p}_C$ then use a rotation matrix to rotate along an axis $\hat{z} = \frac{\vec{\omega}}{ \| \vec{\omega} \| }$ and the angle $\theta = \| \vec{\omega} \|  t$

$$ \vec{p}(\theta) = \vec{p}_C + \mathrm{rot}(\hat{z}, \theta) \left( \vec{p}_0 - \vec{p}_C \right) $$

Comment: That's it! I didn't think to normalize a $\hat z$ against the rotation vector $\vec\omega$. Thanks!